# FMU - Problem reassigning a new value to a variable

Tags: python, fmi, pyfmi

**Main Goal**

Start the FMU with defined start_values ​​and change it in the middle of the process at "ModelExachange".

**Approach**

1. Take the FMU already created from the FMI standard web.
2. Launch it with FMPY.
3. Change value every step with step_finished parameter from simulate_fmu with my_callback function.

**First step**

FMU is loaded perfectly, and the same code is working perfectly at "CoSimulation" but the goal is "ModelExchange".

**The problem**

im trying to modify a value at my_callback function, but this give me the next error:

```
[ERROR] Variable e can only be set after instantiation, in initialization mode, or in event mode.
```

i have tried run event mode before the assignment, or initialization mode, but nothing works.

In this line we modify the value, setting the reference from XML first parameter, and the value second parameter:

```
recorder.fmu.setReal([2], [count])
```

at this point exactly is where im getting the exposed error.

Python Code:

```
import fmpy
from fmpy import *
from ctypes import *

fmpy.plot_library = 'plotly'  # experimental

global count

filename = 'BouncingBall.fmu'


start_values = {
    # variable    start   unit       description
    'g':         (-9.81, 'm/s2'),  # Gravity acting on the ball
    'e':            0.7,           # Coefficient of restitution
}

output = [
    'h',  # Position of the ball
    'v',  # Velocity of the ball
]

def my_callback(time, recorder):
    # use recorder.fmu to access the FMU instance
    count = 0

    if time < 1:
        count = 3
    else:
        count = 1

    recorder.fmu.setReal([2], [count])

    return True

result = simulate_fmu(filename, start_values=start_values, output=output, stop_time=3.0,fmi_type = 'ModelExchange',solver = 'Euler', step_size = 0.001, output_interval = 0.001, step_finished = my_callback)

plot_result(result)
```

My questions:

Any idea how could i solve this?, is possible to do what im trying for ModelExchange?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to use fmpy, but have labeled the your topic with pyfmi, which is a different Python packate

Comment: yeah, true, due the reputation i cant tag my topic with  new tag (FMPy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting these variables using the input argument to fmpy. Using the input argument you can define "timeseries" of inputs. If you set "g" at t=0, it will be applied in the initialization mode (you could also eliminate the need of your `my_callback()` function).

You can take a look at the code to `simulate_fmu` [here](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/fmpy/simulation.py).

Comment: Hello Jan, Thanks for your answer, im basing all my studying on that simulation.py and the documentation, but i dont understand how to implement that example from Input codifying, could you provide me a small example of how to use it?, anyway my intention is try to interact with the fmu every step, and change the values every time i want, could i do that with input?, the first solution was a good way to my goal, but i ran into that problem.

Comment: g is an input and can thus not be set using `apply_start_values` (which is weird...). To set an input, you need to make sure `input.apply()` in the code forwards the inputs. You find an example of how to set inputs in the Input docstring. For g, you would have to have an input time series consisting of "time" and "g", with the value at time=0 (np array with one row).
To interact during simulation, you would indeed have to use the `step_finished` callback or implement your own simulation routine based on the `simulate_ME` function.